# How can I split strings while ignoring the portion in a parentheses in python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a string as follows:
`'Shri Ram Janki Impex Pvt. Ltd. (Lucknow, UP)'`

I want to split it into
`['Shri' 'Ram' 'Janki' 'Impex' 'Pvt.' 'Ltd.' '(Lucknow, UP)']`

I have used `.split()` and it returns me the following:
`['Shri', 'Ram', 'Janki', 'Impex', 'Pvt.', 'Ltd.', '(Lucknow,', 'UP)']`

Using regex:

```
import re
re.split(r'\s+(?=")', c.strip())
```

`['Shri Ram Janki Impex Pvt. Ltd. (Lucknow, UP)']`

I want to do it in Python3.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a negative lookahead to your regex:

```
>>> s = 'Shri Ram Janki Impex Pvt. Ltd. (Lucknow, UP)'
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?!\w+\))', s)
['Shri', 'Ram', 'Janki', 'Impex', 'Pvt.', 'Ltd.', '(Lucknow, UP)']
```

This splits on spaces only if they aren't followed by a word ending in `)`.

If you want to apply this to a dataframe column, I'd compile the regex first and then apply it with a `map`:

```
splitter = re.compile(r'\s+(?!\w+\))')
df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].map(splitter.split)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Any idea how can I perform the similar operation on a dataframe column with similar strings?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do it in two parts:

```
s ='Shri Ram Janki Impex Pvt. Ltd. (Lucknow, UP)'
s.split('(')[0].split() + s.split('.')[2:]
```

**Output**:

```
['Shri', 'Ram', 'Janki', 'Impex', 'Pvt.', 'Ltd.', ' (Lucknow, UP)']
```

Comment: This deletes the `.` characters and only happens to work because the parenthetical part comes after the last one. It will not generalize to other strings.